# Polymer - Updating Element

Tags: polymer

I'm learning Polymer. One item that is challenging me is updating the item of an array. I wish there was a CDN for Polymer so I could put together a fiddle. For now though, I have an element defined like this:

**my-element.html**

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <button on-click="onLoadData">Load Data</button>  
  <button on-click="onTest1Click">Test 1</button>
  <button on-click="onTest2Click">Test 2</button>

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ data ]]" as="element">
    <div><span>[[ element.id ]]</span> - <span>[[ element.status ]]</span></div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ element.children ]]" as="child">
      <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>[[ child.id ]]</span> - <span>[[ child.status ]]</span></div>
    </template>
  </template>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-element',
      properties: {
        data: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() {
            return [];
          }
        }
      },

      onLoadData: function() {
        // Generate some dummy data for the sake of illustration.
        for (var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
          var element = {
            id: i,
            state: 'Initialized',
            description: ''
          };

          element.children = [];
          for (var j=1; j<=5; j++) {
            var child = {
              id: i + '-' + j,
              state: 'Initialized',
              description: ''
            }
            element.children.push(child);
          }

          data.push(element);
        }
      },

      // Setting an individual property value works
      onTest1Click: function() {
        this.set('data.0.children.0.state', 'data set');
      },

      // Setting an entire object value does NOT work.
      onTest2Click: function() {
        var c = this.data[0].children[0];
        c.state = 'data set';
        this.set('data.0.children.0', c);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

For some reason, if I update the property value of an array element (as shown in `onTest1Click`), the UI is updated properly. However, if I update an entire element (as shown in `onTest2Click`), the UI does NOT get updated. In my real problem, I'm updating multiple properties on an element. For that reason, I'm trying to update an array element and not just a property. Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding something? Or, am I going to have to update each property value individually?

Comment: you can use polygit as "CDN" to setup a JSBIN, for example: http://jsbin.com/nemire/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mutate an array, rather than just an object in an array (such as swapping out an entire element in an array), there are array mutation methods similar to `this.set`.

For example, `this.splice('data.0.children', 0, 1, c)` will remove the current item at the 0 index of the child array and replace it with a new one, which is what it appears you're trying to do. There's also `this.shift`, `this.unshift`, `this.push` and `this.pop`. These are all similar to their Array prototype counterparts.

One thing to note is that in your example, you're also not actually swapping out the entire object. When you grab the element from the array, mutate a field, and try and replace it with itself, you're not actually replacing it, so that doesn't actually trigger an update. And since the mutation of the field was done outside of Polymer's notification system, that also doesn't trigger an update. If you replace the item with an actual different object, it will work using splice.
https://jsbin.com/rapomiyaga/1/edit?html,output (This is a modified snapshot of Günter Zöchbauer's jsbin)

If you're not making a copy of the object/a completely new object, you'll want to update each field individually through `this.set`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are going to need to update each property value individually. When you call `set`, Polymer will go to the given path and check if the value has changed. If the value is an object it will compare the references (and not the subproperties). Since the object reference has not changed, it will not update the UI.