# Polymer 1 nested dom-if within dom-repeat not updating when data changes

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

How do you make `dom-if` templates within `dom-repeat`'s update when the data changes??

Example here http://jsbin.com/xatala/edit?html,output

In the example the data changes after 1.5 seconds but the dom-if's inside the template aren't re-evaluated/rendered. You can see this in the console.log. The data has changed but the view isn't updated.

How would you make this work and what is the reasoning behind it?!

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182212/polymer-updating-element/). Your problem is not directly related to `dom-if` or `dom-repeat`, but rather about updating `Arrays` and `Objects` in Polymer.

Comment: Thanks @Maria, that's a helpful pointer... it's difficult in my situation as I'm manipulating data outside of element... will have to re-evaluate the way I'm doing it.

Comment: Does `this.set('myItems.1.isGood', true);` not work? This allows Polymer to know you are setting a property within a specific array item. This isn't practical in all situations, admittedly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is example that works: http://jsbin.com/nejadibuju/edit?html,console,output

```
<template is="dom-if" 
  if="{{arrayItem(myItems.*, index, 'isGood')}}">
      [[item.title]] is SOOO good.
</template>
```

What you were missing is:

> [Explicit bindings to array items by index isn’t supported](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#array-binding)

Some explanations are added in the Bin. 
Related links:

[Polymer, binding to array items not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209556/polymer-binding-to-array-items-not-working)

http://plnkr.co/edit/aOmw4e?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! That explains it pretty well.